# creating custom middleware not working in django?

Tags: django, middleware

Here I am trying to update user's last time visit  by using the custom middleware. But this is not working.It is not updating the last_visit time in the database.

What am i doing wrong here ?

models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_visit = models.DateTimeField(default=now(), blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class CheckUserLastVisitMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            Staff.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk).update(last_visit=now())

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'organization.views.CheckUserLastVisitMiddleware',
```

Comment: Unrelated, but this `Staff.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)`is wrong - `Staff` has it's own pk, which is NOT the same as `User.pk`, so you're not updating the correct `Staff` record(s) (or, if it happens, it's only by accident). The proper query would be `Staff.objects.filter(user=request.user)`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers before it was  `User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk).update(staff__last_visit=now())` and it says no filed name with `staff__last_visit` so I changed to this .Thanks now I will change it to that

Comment: May I kindly suggest you [read this](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) and think twice about your approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your middleware comes after the AuthenticationMiddleware in the settings. Otherwise `request.user.is_authenticated` will always be `False`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # your middleware should be added here or even further down
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I have added it on the last